# Set global path for pylint/pycodestyle in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, pylint, pycodestyle

I'm trying to set up VSCode to use the user level installed pylint and pycodestyle so that when using a virtual environment I can keep using linting, without actually having it installed in the environment and appearing in the requirements.txt.

According to pip show these are found in /home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages however adding

```
"python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycodestyle",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/",
```

To my user settings.json just results in a invalid path error. I can't figure out what to link to here, none of the obvious options (pep8.py or pycodestle.py in that directory, pylint/lint.py, just the pylint directory itself, etc) work for either of them. Can anyone help? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 if that makes a difference to where they're located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path `"/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` is where the Python code that you installed as a user lives, not where the `pylint` command lives as the `"python.linting.pylintPath"` wants. You probably want "/home/alex/.local/bin/pylint`.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly it! Thanks

Comment: I would also recommend using [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) to manage installed Python tools from PyPI.